# StringBuilder ReplaceAt functionality

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have a stringbuilder that I'm manipulating several times, and I need to replace strings within it with strings of varying lengths.

```
sb = new StringBuilder("This has {Count} Values.  Your search was '{SearchText}'.  Did you mean '{DidYouMean}'?")
//get the replacement areas, this would search for the field names within {}
MatchCollection matches = GetReplacementAreas(sb);

int indexOffset=0;
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
   //fields is a dictionary containing keys that match the fields
   sb.ReplaceAt(m.Index,m.Length,fields[m.Value]); 
}
```

Obviously ReplaceAt doesnt exist.  I'm about to write it myself.  Anybody else already done so?

Comment: Not really sure why you wouldn't just use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) or [StringBuilder.AppendFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendformat.aspx) existing functionality?

Comment: I take it you can't just use the standard `Replace` method once you have the matches telling you what you are replacing?

Comment: @MikeGuthrie: I assume the idea is that what is in the curly brackets could be anything and it is matched up with a data object and dynamically performs the substiutions. ie at compile time you don't know what is going to be in the string so you can't pass the right values as parameters to `String.Format` or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
#if EXTENSIONS_SUPPORTED
    public static StringBuilder ReplaceAt(this StringBuilder sb, string value, int index, int count)
    {
        return StringBuilderExtensions.ReplaceAt(sb, value, index, count);
    }
#endif

    public static StringBuilder ReplaceAt(StringBuilder sb, string value, int index, int count)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            sb.Remove(index, count);
        }
        else
        {
            int lengthOfValue = value.Length;

            if (lengthOfValue > count)
            {
                string valueToInsert = value.Substring(count);
                sb.Insert(index + count, valueToInsert);
            }
            if (lengthOfValue < count)
            {
                sb.Remove(index + count, lengthOfValue - count);
            }

            char[] valueChars = value.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfValue; i++)
            {
                sb[index + i] = valueChars[i];
            }
        }

        return sb;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this isn't a particularly performant operation.  `StringBuilder`s are designed to efficiently add to the end, not to efficiently modify what has been already added.  You'll be losing most of the benefits of using a `StringBuilder` if you use a method like this a lot.

Comment: As opposed to creating a bunch of strings in memory for every replace operation?  More efficient make room by shifting bytes especially when the buffer has normal slack at the end then creating whole new strings.

Comment: I didn't say that that would be the best way to do it, merely that this is only marginally better.  Creating the string in a mutable structure by moving along performing the replaces as they are found would be dramatically more performant than either option you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For accuracy, enorl76 answer looked promising but will not work with Unicode strings, in particular Unicode characters of 2-bytes in width. Here's enorl76 answer mocked up in a [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y0JdZt) for an examination.

Here's a one implementation to solve this, a .Net Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DdiKZl).

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

//Created for 
//http://metadataconsulting.blogspot.com/2019/03/A-Unicode-ReplaceAt-string-extension-method-handles-Unicode-string-properly.html

public static class Program
{


 const char cEMPTY = '\0'; 
    static readonly string EMPTY = cEMPTY.ToString(); 

    public static string UnicodeReplaceAt(this string str, int offset, char replaceChar)
    {
        int count = 1; //number of times to replace
        string replaceBy = replaceChar.ToString();
        return new StringInfo(str).ReplaceByPosition(replaceBy, offset, count).String;
    }

    public static StringInfo ReplaceByPosition(this StringInfo str, string replaceBy, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (replaceBy != EMPTY)
            return str.RemoveByTextElements(offset, count).InsertByTextElements(offset, replaceBy);
        else
            return str.RemoveByTextElements(offset, count);
    }

    public static StringInfo RemoveByTextElements(this StringInfo str, int offset, int count)
    { 
  //Tue 20-Aug-19 11:32am metadataconsulting.ca - replaceat index > string.len return orginal string
  if (offset > str.LengthInTextElements)
   return str;

        return new StringInfo(string.Concat(
            str.SubstringByTextElements(0, offset),
            offset + count < str.LengthInTextElements
                ? str.SubstringByTextElements(offset + count, str.LengthInTextElements - count - offset)
                : string.Empty
            ));
    }
    public static StringInfo InsertByTextElements(this StringInfo str, int offset, string insertStr)
    {
        //Tue 20-Aug-19 11:32am metadataconsulting.ca - replaceat index > string.len return orginal string
  if (offset > str.LengthInTextElements)
   return str;

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str.String))
            return new StringInfo(insertStr);

        return new StringInfo(string.Concat(
            str.SubstringByTextElements(0, offset),
            insertStr,
            str.LengthInTextElements - offset > 0 ? str.SubstringByTextElements(offset, str.LengthInTextElements - offset) : ""
        ));
    }

    public static string SubsituteStringStringBuilder(this string s, int idx, char replaceChar)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || idx >= s.Length || idx < 0)
            return s;

        return new StringBuilder(s).Remove(idx, 1).Insert(idx, replaceChar.ToString()).ToString();
    }

    public static string ReplaceAtSubstring(this string s, int idx, char replaceChar)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || idx >= s.Length || idx < 0)
            return s;

        return s.Substring(0, idx) + replaceChar.ToString() + s.Substring(idx + replaceChar.ToString().Length, s.Length - (idx + replaceChar.ToString().Length));

    }

    public static string ReplaceAtStringManipulation(this string s, int idx, char replaceChar)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || idx >= s.Length || idx < 0)
            return s;

        return s.Remove(idx, 1).Insert(idx, replaceChar.ToString());
    }

    public static string ReplaceAtLinq(this string value, int index, char newchar)
    {
        if (value.Length <= index)
            return value;
        else
            return string.Concat(value.Select((c, i) => i == index ? newchar : c));
    }

    public static string ReplaceAtCharArray(this string input, uint index, char newChar)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || index >= input.Length)
            return input;

        char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
        chars[index] = newChar;
        return new string(chars);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        //In .NET 4.5 and later also UTF-16 is supported
        //Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;  

  //é  Latin Small Letter e with Acute U+00E9 - single byte Unicode character
  // Smiling Face with Smiling Eyes Emoji U+1F60A - double byte Unicode character
  // Multiple Musical Notes Emoji U+1F3B6 - - double byte Unicode character
  // Fire Emoji U+1F525 -- double byte Unicode character

  Console.WriteLine("Unicode String Replace At Issue");
  Console.WriteLine("Lets examine string \"é-\"");  
        Console.WriteLine("é- is length of " + "é-".Length + ", but there are ONLY 4 characters! Why not len=4?"); 
  Console.WriteLine(" are double byte UNICODE characters (> \\u10000) of width or len 2 each ");
  Console.WriteLine("é- below will replace space after lasting character '-' (position 4) with a sub using most common techniques seen online"); 

  Console.WriteLine(); 

  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("é- using ReplaceAtCharArray".ReplaceAtCharArray(4, 'X'));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));

        sw.Restart();
        Console.WriteLine("é- using ReplaceAtLinq".ReplaceAtLinq(4, 'Y'));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));

        sw.Restart();
        Console.WriteLine("é- using ReplaceAtStringManipulation".ReplaceAtStringManipulation(4, 'Z'));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));

        sw.Restart();
        Console.WriteLine("é- using ReplaceAtSubstring".ReplaceAtSubstring(4, 'A'));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));

        sw.Restart();
        Console.WriteLine("é- using SubsituteStringStringBuilder".SubsituteStringStringBuilder(4, 'W'));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));

  sw.Restart();
        Console.WriteLine("é- using UnicodeReplaceAt".UnicodeReplaceAt(4, '4'));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));

  Console.WriteLine(); 
  Console.WriteLine("UnicodeReplaceAt replaces properly at position 4 in zero based index string");
        Console.WriteLine(); 
  sw.Restart();
        Console.Write("é- using UnicodeReplaceAt(0, '0')".UnicodeReplaceAt(0, '0'));
        sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine(" in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));
  sw.Restart();
        Console.Write("é- using UnicodeReplaceAt(1, '1')".UnicodeReplaceAt(1, '1'));
        sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine(" in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));
  sw.Restart();
        Console.Write("é- using UnicodeReplaceAt(2, '2')".UnicodeReplaceAt(2, '2'));
        sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine(" in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));
  sw.Restart();
        Console.Write("é- using UnicodeReplaceAt(3, '3')".UnicodeReplaceAt(3, '3'));
        sw.Stop();
  Console.WriteLine(" in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));
  sw.Restart();
        Console.Write("é- using UnicodeReplaceAt(4, '4')".UnicodeReplaceAt(4, '4'));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));
     Console.Write("é-".UnicodeReplaceAt(5, '5')+" using UnicodeReplaceAt(5, '5') - this is beyond end of string, so return orginal string");
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" in {0} ticks.", sw.ElapsedTicks.ToString("N0"));



  Console.WriteLine(); 
  Console.WriteLine("String.Replace works, but replaces all characters, not at specific location as above functions");
        Console.WriteLine(); 
  Console.Write("é- using String.Replace".Replace("", "+") + "('', '+')");


    }
}
```